# Python --- TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python

I was trying to run this code:

Thats something I am doing that to improve myself...

```
import sqlite3 as sq


def add_user(username, passwd):
    database = sq.connect("database.db")
    cursor = database.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""insert into maintable values (?, ?, ?)""",
                   (username, passwd, ""))
    database.commit()


def add_lesson(username, lesson):
    database = sq.connect("database.db")
    cursor = database.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""select * from maintable where kullad=?""", (username,))
    if cursor.fetchone()[2] != "":
        lessons_dict = {lesson: 0}
        cursor.execute(
            """update maintable set lessons=? where kullad=?""", (lessons_dict, username,))
        database.commit()

    else:
        cursor.fetchone()[2][lesson] = 0
        cursor.execute(
            """update maintable set lessons=? where kullad=?""", (lessons_dict, username,))
        database.commit()

add_lesson("user", "lesson1")
```

---

When I try to run this I get this error:

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 29, in <module>
    add_lesson("user", "lesson1")
  File "main.py", line 24, in add_lesson
    cursor.fetchone()[2][lesson] = 0
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

---

Comment: your `cursor.fetchone()` returned `None`, check for that before doing queries into the result

Comment: Now it is working. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your SQL may be like this:

```
cursor.execute("""select * from maintable where kullad="?"""", (username,))
```

string in SQL should be surrounded by quotes.